# Is the duration time for Power Apps Dataflow from Azure SQL to Dataverse really slow and error messages this terrible?

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, dataflow, cds, dataverse

I have a table in a Azure SQL Database which contains approximately 10 cols and 1.7 million rows. There data in each cell is mostly null/varchar(30).

When running a dataflow to a new table in Dataverse, I have two issues:

1. It takes around 14 hours (around 100k rows or so per hour)
2. It fails after 14 hours with the great error message (**** is just some entity names I have removed):

> Dataflow name,Entity name,Start time,End time,Status,Upsert count,Error count,Status details

> ****** - *******,,1.5.2021 9:47:20 p.m.,2.5.2021 9:51:27 a.m.,Failed,,,There was a problem refreshing >the dataflow. please try again later. (request id: 5edec6c7-3d3c-49df-b6de-e8032999d049).

> ****** - *******,*******,1.5.2021 9:47:43 p.m.,2.5.2021 9:51:26 a.m.,Aborted,0,0,

> Table name,Row id,Request url,Error details

> *******,,,Job failed due to timeout : A task was canceled.

1. Is it really so that this should take 14 hours :O ?
2. Are there any verbose logging I can enable to get a more friendly error message?

Comment: I did ADF integraion into Dataverse when it was called CDS (as the back end of Dynamics 365). I assume it's still terrible and slow despite the name change. What I did learn is that you should create five _Non-Interactive_ users and load data in parallel through those five users. I also learnt the that `contact` and `account` entities were definitely the slowest.

Comment: BTW your error is "Job failed due to timeout " and if this always happens after 14 hours or so, then it's a hard timeout limit. The only solution is to... load less or load it faster.